# Formatted text rendered wrongly in question but is correct in edit preview

Tags: bug, markdown, formatting

I stumbled upon a [question](https://superuser.com/q/1375964/226624) that has some incorrectly rendered block of formatted text:

[image: Formatting of the actual question]

I wanted to edit and correct this but was surprised to see that in the editor it looks like this (no change made by me):

[image: Markdown and formatting in preview]

So in the Markdown, three backticks are used, which should be the right thing for a block of formatted text, and the preview renders this correctly.  However, in the final result, it is rendered wrongly for some reason.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330102/355310

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fundamentally - we didn't have code fences then. We do now. Essentially - the conversion from markdown to rendered markup happens *once* - when the post is posted.

For extra fun - since its an odd number of backticks, the first pair in the opening code fence was "one" set of unformulated characters, the last and the first of the closing pair, and the 2 at the end each acted as a pair of backticks. So essentially, we were wrapping all that in *one* backtick

And the edit window was crunching the markdown on the fly to show you what you *would* see, so it ignored the obsolete markdown rendering

A single character *unrelated* edit caused the system to crunch the markdown, and all (the formatting) is good again